# show hide div / play stop audio

Tags: javascript, html, audio, hide, show

I try to learn javascript/ jquery. (and sorry for my english ^^)
I have to show or hide some divs in my web page. That's ok, this working fine with javascript.
But for exemple, when div1 is visible (display:yes) i would like to play a sound and when it's not visible (display:none) stop sound.
AND 
I don't want two sound files are played at the same time, if a new div is open, then the sound file is played and stop all other sound. Here is an exemple but it doesnt work, 
nothing happens :( Thank you.

Javascript

```
<script src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

if($('#mydiv').css('display') == 'block')
    {

    $('audio').each(function() {
        $(this).play();
    });

} else {

    $('audio').each(function() {
        $(this).pause();
    });

}

</script>
```

HTML

```
<div id="mydiv" style="display:block">
<audio id="audio">
<source src="voice.mp3"></source>
</audio>Hi</div>


<div id="mydiv2" style="display:none">
<audio id="audio2">
<source src="voice_2.mp3"></source>
</audio>Hey</div>


<div id="mydiv3" style="display:none">
<audio id="audio3">
<source src="voice_3.mp3"></source>
</audio>Yep</div>
```

Comment: for a start you need to put the audio in the div tags, as it is at the mo you will be showing all 3 audios at the same time.

Comment: `yes` isn't a valid value for `display` . https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display

Comment: thank you for your answer, I just make the changes but I think there is a problem with the javascript. because the sound file will not work when the div is visible.

Answer (score 1):

From where you have invented the display:yes :D
you can use display:block there..

Here is the link of all the display property.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_display&preval=inline

Comment: thank you for your answer, I just make the changes but I think there is a problem with the javascript. because the sound file will not work when the div is visible.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this, with Firefox I think it needs stop() rather than pause, though not sure. Notice I've added a number 1 to the first div and audio, muck around with it as you see fit.

```js
$(function(){    
$('button').on('click',function(e){
 $('audio').each(function(){
  this.pause(); // Stop playing
   this.currentTime = 0; // Reset time
  }); 
    $('div').css('display','none');
    $('#mydiv'+this.innerHTML).toggle();   
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>1</button><button>2</button><button>3</button><br><br>
<div id="mydiv1" style="display:none">div1
<audio id="audio1" autoplay>
<source src="voice1.mp3"></source>
</audio>
</div>
<div id="mydiv2" style="display:none">div2
<audio id="audio2">
<source src="voice_2.mp3"></source>
</audio>
</div>
<div id="mydiv3" style="display:none">div 3
<audio id="audio3">
<source src="voice_3.mp3"></source>
</audio>
 </div>
```

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uyn5snf0/)

uncomment out the pause and play, forgot to do that, with Firefox I think it needs stop() rather than pause

Comment: Sorry, stuck into something else at the mo, Back in a short while and I'll have a look.

Comment: Updated the Jquery, Try now.

Comment: Div show/hide work perfectly but audio doesn't play, sorry. But again, thank you for your time Billy :)